# MSBuild is saying I need a Main method for a library compilation

Tags: c#, msbuild, csc

I'm trying to use MSBuild to compile my ASP.NET MVC3 applicaiton. Since DLL's don't require a `Main` method and I have specified that the target is a Library, why is the compiler throwing the following exception:

```
CSC : error CS5001: Program 'c:\MvcApplication1\web\bin\MvcApplication1.dll' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point[C:\MvcApplication1\web\MvcApplication1.csproj]
```

Here's the .csproj file:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
        <AssemblyName>MvcApplication1</AssemblyName>
        <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="*.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="..\lib\*.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)" Condition="!Exists('$(OutputPath)')" />
        <Csc References="@(Reference)" Sources="@(Compile)" OutputAssembly="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll" />
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(Reference)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Csc` should have a `TargetType` of `library`. The default is supposed to be Library (see MSDN below) although in this case it doesn't seem to be the case.

Change you `<Csc` step as follows:

```
<Csc TargetType="library" References="@(Reference)"  ....  />
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22HTTP://SCHEMAS.MICROSOFT.COM/DEVELOPER/MSBUILD/2003#CSC%22%29;k%28%22HTTP://SCHEMAS.MICROSOFT.COM/DEVELOPER/MSBUILD/2003#TARGET%22%29;k%28VS.XMLEDITOR%29&rd=true) re **TargetType**:

> Specifies the file format of the output file. This parameter can have
>   a value of library, which creates a code library, exe, which creates a
>   console application, module, which creates a module, or winexe, which
>   creates a Windows program. The default value is library. For more
>   information, see /target (C# Compiler Options).

Comment: Yes, I think I'm setting the `/target:library` csc switch with `<OutputType>Library</OutputType>` in my .csproj file.

Comment: This is the TargetType on the "Csc". Although it should be Library by default

Comment: Yes, you're right: I updated `<Csc References="@(Reference)" Sources="@(Compile)" OutputAssembly="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll" />` to include `TargetType="Library"` and it works now. I had thought it was the `<OutputType>` element that would do it but was wrong. Thanks very much.

Comment: @nbsp And given that MSDN says that "library" is the default for the TargetType :), Although csc.exe says "exe" is the default.